# dnsmasq's server option doesn't work for a specific domain

Tags: dns, networkmanager, dnsmasq

I have configured `dnsmasq` as a local DNS server. Now since my ISP does not resolve `some-company.sharepoint.com` I want to use Google's servers for the domain `sharepoint.com`. (See [here](http://ageofwindows.com/dns_probe_finished_nxdomain/) for the windows solution.)

```
$ grep "^[^#]" /etc/dnsmasq.conf 
server=/sharepoint.com/8.8.8.8
server=/sharepoint.com/8.8.4.4
listen-address=127.0.0.1
```

I have configured `ǸetworkManager` to use `dnsmasq`

```
$ cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf 
# Configuration file for NetworkManager.
# See "man 5 NetworkManager.conf" for details.
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

and restarted.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

My `resolv.conf` now looks like this:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search fritz.box
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Using `drill` to test:

```
$ drill some-company.sharepoint.com
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NXDOMAIN, id: 21965
...
```

While the Google server works...

```
$ drill some-company.sharepoint.com @8.8.8.8
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 48098
```

The [docs](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/setup.html) describing the `server` option say this option is general:

> Dnsmasq has the ability to direct DNS queries for certain domains to
>   specific upstream nameservers. This feature was added for use with
>   VPNs but it is fully general.

Comment: `8.8.8.8` is an open recursive nameserver, it is not an authoritative nameserver for `sharepoint.com`. You should use in your dnsmasq configuration the authorative servers IP addresses, hence `40.90.4.203`, `64.4.48.203`, `13.107.24.203` and `13.107.160.203`.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The problem of resolving the host with my ISPs DNS seems to be resolved so I had to use Wireshark to see which DNS server is used by `dnsmasq` and it is clearly sending requests to my router (which seems to be a DNS server itself) and not to one of the given IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

I could not recreate the situation you encountered.

I assumed a example domain `example.com` cannot be resolved by the resolver I use. I configured dnsmasq to send questions having this domain to use `8.8.8.8`. And dnsmasq's local instance sent questions of this domain (`example.com`) to Google DNS Resolver only rather than the default resolver I use.